# Receive passed data in vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying, with no luck to use some data that get passed into a vue component. I have no problem receiving it, but i don't get how i can manipulate it the way i want.

In the component i want to se its "title" variable to the value passed, if any. But if no value is passed i want to set it to a default value, which in this case is "lorem". I cant use the props default value attribute for a reason that does not matter here.

How would i do this?

Code:

```
<Meta title="test" />
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Meta",
  data() {
    return {
      title: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    thetitle() {
      return this.title ? "" : "lorem ipsum";
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document
      .querySelector('meta[name="description"]')
      .setAttribute("content", this.title);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`title` should be defined inside the `props` option since it's received from the parent component :

```js
export default {
  name: "Meta",
  props:['title'];
  computed: {
    thetitle() {
      return this.title ? "" : "lorem ipsum";
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document
      .querySelector('meta[name="description"]')
      .setAttribute("content", this.title);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi! Thank's for your answer. However, if i do not pass any title it gets undefined..

Comment: Please explain more the issue

Comment: In my parent component i pass a value. If no value are passed i want to set the title to some random string like "lorem ipsum". But if a value is passed i want to set it to that value. Whatever value it gets i want to be able to use in my child component as a variable.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Had to change a little

Answer (score 0):

let's take some scenario to understand this.

```
export default {
  name: "Meta",
  props:{
    title: {
       type: [String,null,undefined],
       defualt: 'lorem'
    }
  };
  computed: {
    modifiedTitle() {
      return this.title || "lorem ipsum";
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document
      .querySelector('meta[name="description"]')
      .setAttribute("content", this.modifiedTitle);
  }
};
```

**1.  test="randon truethy string"**

```
<Meta title="test" />
```

here we are passing a string in title. so the default function of title props will not call. and in modified title props this.title get truthy value .***so return value of modifiedTitle is 'randon truthy string'***

**2.test =""  or null**

```
<Meta title="test" />
```

here we are passing a string as an empty string or null. even in this case also default function will not call.  and modifiedTitle props this.title is falsy value ***so these will return "lorem ipsum".***

**3.pass test = undefined**

```
   <Meta title="test" />
```

here we are passing undefined. so in this case default function of props is called as a set default value to the title which is "lorem". in modifiedTitle props this.title has truthy value (which is set by default function -> 'lorem'). ***so modified computedProps return 'lorem'***

**4. Don't pass the test as props**

```
<Meta />
```

in this, we are not passing props. so it will call the default function and further value set according to point 3. ***it also returns 'lorem' in modifiedTitle props.***

Answer (score 0):

***Suggestion :*** *Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: meta*

***Observation :*** `this.title ? "" : "lorem ipsum"` - This condition is not correct. It will return empty if title passed. Hence, You can use simple if statement **:**

```
if (!this.title) {
  return 'lorem ipsum'
}
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('metaapp', {
  computed: {
    theTitle: function() {
        if (!this.title) {
        return 'lorem ipsum'
      }
      return this.title;
    }
  },
  props: ['title'],
  template: '<h3>{{ theTitle }}</h3>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <MetaApp :title="msg"></MetaApp>
</div>
```